# Why doesn't a calculated amount update when the factory updates?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple factory like this

```
angular.module('posBitcoinApp')
.factory('invoiceData', function ($http, $interval) {

var blockchainInfoExchangeRates = {};

var getLatestExchangeRates = function() {

    $http.get('https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/IDR/')
    .success(function(response) {
        blockchainInfoExchangeRates.IDR = response.last;
    });
};

$interval(getLatestExchangeRates, 60000);
getLatestExchangeRates();

return {
    exchangeRates: blockchainInfoExchangeRates
};

});
```

Then in one of my controllers I have...

```
angular.module('posBitcoinApp')
.controller('InvoiceCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $location, invoiceData) {

$scope.invoiceData = invoiceData;
$scope.invoiceData.btcAmount = parseFloat($scope.invoiceData.idrAmount / $scope.invoiceData.exchangeRates.IDR).toFixed(8);
```

So every minute the exchange rates get updated. However, the calculated the BTC value ($scope.invoiceData.btcAmount) does not auto update. What am I missing? Something need to be watched? $scope.apply() somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Your controller should watch on `invoiceData.exchangeRates`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you refresh data on factory it would not reflect as you are returning the data. Instead of that You have to refresh scope.invoiceData.btcAmount for every one minute interval.

```
Var updateBTC = function(){
//call to factory if you want to avoid having an interval inside factory to update data and use the result in the below statement.
   $scope.invoiceData.btcAmount = parseFloat($scope.invoiceData.idrAmount / $scope.invoiceData.exchangeRates.IDR).toFixed(8);
};

$interval(updateBTC, 60000);
```